# Scrapy save every link whole domain

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

**Introduction**

currently im working on a crawler, which saves every link of a domain to a .csv-file

**Problem**
In my console, i can see, which links its following, but my items are still empty.
I get something like:
[image: click me]

**Here is my default code**

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from ..items import LinkextractorItem

class TopArtSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "topart"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.topart-online.com/de/Bambus-Kunstbaeume/l-KAT11'
    ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS' : ['Link'] }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    
    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = LinkextractorItem()
        link = response.xpath('a/@href')
        items['Link'] = link
        yield items
```

my start_url is just a category of the domain, because i dont want to wait too long, as long as im trying to build the correct spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPATH selector isn't searching th entire DOM. Change it to this.

```
link = response.xpath('//a/@href')
```

The `//` searches the entire DOM.

You also are not grabbing the data, so you need to include `getall()` which will give you a list. You could also use a for loop, to loop around each link which I think is probably the approach you should do.

```
link = response.xpath('//a/@href')
        for a in link: 
            items['Link'] = a.get()
            yield items
```

Comment: my spider actually follows every link also links for espanol, italia etc. with allow_domains, i can set, that it only follows /de urls?

Comment: and i have the feeling, that i runs endless, how do set a method that i stops after crawling every /de link?

Comment: You probably don't want to follow all links in that case. So deleting following part of the LinkExtractor and putting.LinkExtractor(allow='de/').

Comment: my spider is running since ~10 mins but didnt stop, are there so many links or is it broken?